# MySQL: Get all staff that have not been reviewed in the last month

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database where you can add reviews on staff.
I would like a statement that gets all staff that have not been reviewed in the last month.

So far I have:

```
SELECT id, max(date), staff_id, reviewer_id FROM `review` WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY staff
```

This however cuts out the dates I want to check against, if I could use the max(date) column in the where clause that would be great, something like:

```
SELECT id, max(date) as testdate, staff_id, reviewer_id FROM `review` WHERE testdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY staff
```

that would get the result I want but this can not be done in SQL

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you reqire MAX(date) when what you have asked for is all staff who have not been reviwed in last month. For that `select id from staff where id not in (select staff_id from review where date >DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) )`

Comment: Ah that worked perfectly thank you! I guess I was thinking about it all wrong trying to use max(date) to only grab the most recent to check against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
select id from staff where
id not in 
(select staff_id from review where date >DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) )
```

-- Update to get review date

```
select a.id from staff a where
a.id not in 
(select b.staff_id from review b where b.date >DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
inner join
(select max(r.reviewDate), r.staff_id from review r group by r.staff_id) test 
on test.staff_id=a.id
```

Comment: This works well, just having trouble showing a date if one exists.

Comment: You want to display what date, you are displaying staff who do not have an entry in review table so there are no review date for them

Comment: This returns all staff who have never had a review and those that have not had one in the last month. I want the date of their last review if they have had one. So I can use this to show how overdue it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use HAVING:

```
SELECT id, max(date) as testdate, staff_id, reviewer_id FROM `review`  GROUP BY staff HAVING  testdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

However, you will also not see any staff who have *never* had a review. To get these guys, you will need to join to your `staff` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT id, max(date), staff_id, reviewer_id
    FROM `reviews`
    GROUP BY staff
    HAVING max( date ) < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1
    MONTH )
```

Normally we have to use having clause in group by instead of where clause, since aggregate function comparisons are not allowed in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
select id,staff_id,max(date),reviewer_id from review where date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) group by staff_id;
```

Comment: This did work thank you, however as @realcals mentioned it would not pickup people who have never had a review.